# Swift - Child controller causes 'Receiver has no segue with identifier'

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I have a ViewController that has a child controller with a dynamic tableview.

On tapping a table cell I need to segue to a new view.

I've tried all kinds of methods, including directly control dragging from the cell (resulting in a 'detached controller' warning) with little success and the current situation is as follows.

Child Controller (currentName, currentType are globals that can be picked up by the parent, myHome)

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
    currentName = "John"
    currentType = 1
    let segueVC = myHome()
    segueVC.segueToMain()
}
```

Parent Controller (myHome)

```
func segueToMain() {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("home_myMain", sender: self)
    }
}
```

I know this is probably horrendous but it appears to work fine in that it stores the data and gets to the parent function. However the attempt to segue causes the 'Receiver has no segue with identifier' error. The segue id is exactly correct. It links to a Navigation Controller.

I have a feeling that I need some delegates etc but I'm not really sure how to deal with them. Getting rid of the navigation controller and segue direct to view didn't make any difference.

Any help with how to get this segue to trigger would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

In relation to answers suggesting the segue direct from the child, here is the setup which seems to result in a 'detached' controller error. For the record, I would love to use this method but all attempts failed.

The Parent Controller (A) builds a PageMenu class that gets its page structure from Controller B. B has a table with cells directly segued to another view.

A constructs the menu as follows

```
self.addChildViewController(self.pageMenu!)
self.view.addSubview(pageMenu!.view)
self.pageMenu!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

PageMenu uses class B as the template for each menu page.

There is no physical link between A and B on the storyboard - only that the class for A sets B as a child.

Segues from B fail with a 'detached controller' error so maybe there's something I'm missing from the child setup?

Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify, Segue is connected from the Parent ViewController (myHome), right ?

Comment: the code looks fine, could you add a screenshot of your storyboard. would be easier to see if there's a problem with the setup.

Comment: @UditS Yes that's correct

Answer (score 0):

You can't just allocate a new instance of your parent view controller and ask it to perform a segue - As you are instantiating the view controller directly, it won't be associated with the storyboard, this is why you get an exception stating that that view controller doesn't have a segue of the specified identifier.

Even if you did instantiate a new instance from the storyboard you would still get an error as that new instance wouldn't be on screen, resulting in a message that you attempted to present a view controller on a view controller that isn't in the view hierarchy.

You need your child view controller to have a reference to the parent view controller instance that contains it and then invoke the segue using that instance.

Also, there is no need for the `dispatch_async` - the tableview delegate method will be invoked on the main queue already.

Finally, by convention, class names start with an upper case letter, so `myHome` should be `MyHome` (or even better, something like `MyHomeViewController`)

Comment: Thanks Paul - as with Chathuranga's post, my preferred way to do this would be a direct segue from the table cell which works until the controller is set as a child. I've edited the original post to see if it helps get an answer as to why the child is thought to be detached.